# Backshifting in Reported Speech

Tags: backshifting

> The exec was making a presentation to the company board."Computers
>   have allowed us to cut costs," he explained. "We expect even more
>   dramatic improvements as computers become increasingly
>   self-sufficient."

I don't use backshifting because the situation is still true. Am I right?

The exec was making a presentation to the company board. He told them computers have allowed them to cut costs. Then he explained that they expect even more dramatic improvements as computers become increasingly self-sufficient.

Comment: That seems correct; however, the use of *them* and *they* is slightly ambiguous. Who? The board members, the company, or somebody else? In the original, the exec says *us* and *we*. Is that him and the other board members, him and a different group, or the company as a whole? (For example, *He told them* [the board] *computers have allowed* ***the company*** *to cut costs*, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gray area.  Keeping the reported speech in the present tense is acceptable if you're reporting an event in the simple past, and the reported situation is still true:

> The exec **made** a presentation. He said that computers **have** allowed them to cut costs. Then he explained that they **expect** even more dramatic improvements.   (situation is still true now)
>
> The exec **made** a presentation. He said that computers **had** allowed them to cut costs. Then he explained that they **were expecting** even more dramatic improvements.   (situation may or may not be true now)

On the other hand, when you use past progressive 'The exec was making a presentation ...', you're more forcefully setting a full scenario in the past, like a storyteller.  As a result, it's more necessary to backshift the reported speech:

> The exec **was making** a presentation. He said that computers **had** allowed them to cut costs. Then he explained that they **were expecting** even more dramatic improvements.