# Indirect of live ,if i still live in that place

Tags: reported-speech

direct   : she said to him, "where do you live ?"

indirect : she asked him where he lived.

does this mean, he does not live there anymore but used to live in the past.

indirect : she asked him where he lives. ( incorrect why ? )

this is indicating more like he still lives there.

how to convey that he still lives there?

Comment: There haver been many questions on [backshifting of tenses in reported speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180448/backshifting-in-reported-speech). It isn't necessarily incorrect to say "She asked him where he lives" if the question was recent and he still lives in the same place.

Comment: What @Kate said. We *usually* "backshift" the verb in the actual "question" part of an utterance like your second example. Which is perhaps better illustrated by *He **asked** me what my name **was*** - much more likely than *...what my name **is***, even though in nearly all cases there's not the remotest chance that the speaker's name has changed since the reported speech event in the past.